# configure VS Code CSS formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, js-beautify

For year's I've used [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify), first in Atom and recently in VS Code using the [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) extension. Now it looks like that extension has been deprecated, and js-beautify is now [built-in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css).

But with the extension I could add a `.jsbeautifyrc` file to specify formatting options, **in particular `end_with_newline` to add a newline at the end of the file**. I could even specify file type-specific options.

```json
{
…
  "end_with_newline": true,
  "wrap_line_length": 0,
  "css": {
    "selector-separator-newline": false
  }
}
```

When I disable the extension and use the internal VS Code js-beautify, it no longer seems to honor the `.jsbeautifyrc` settings, and removes the trailing newline.

How do I configure the formatting settings of the internal VS Code js-beautify implementation?

Answer (score 1):

If you search the settings for `css format` you will see there are a few there: newlines between selectors and rules, etc.

So you could disable `CSS > Format: Newlines Between Selectors` for example.

In addition, you can make `css`-specific settings like this (in your `settings.json`):

```
"[css]": {
  "files.insertFinalNewline": true
}
```

And make sure  the setting `CSS > Format: Enable` is set to `true`. (the default is `true`)

Comment: So does the VS Code built-in Beautify implementation ignore my `.jsbeautifyrc` file? Does anything built-in to VS Code look at `.jsbeautifyrc`? (e.g. What about the HTML formatter?)

Comment: Interestingly enabling the VS Code setting `Files: Insert Final Newline` actually _adds the newline during built-in formatting_ we well, even though the description for that setting only mentions "… when saving it". It is very good that they made the built-in formatter aware of that setting, but one might not know just from reading the description that it affected the formatter as well.